# xcode command line tools homebrew warning

Tags: xcode, command-line, homebrew

When running `brew doctor` i get this error

```
Warning: Your compilers are different from the standard versions for your Xcode.
If you have Xcode 4.3 or newer, you should install the Command Line Tools for
Xcode from within Xcode's Download preferences.
Otherwise, you should reinstall Xcode.
```

I have re-installed xcode multiple times and reinstalled the cli tools everytime.

Comment: I have the same issue. Any luck so far ?

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to reinstall Xcode. Go to Xcode preferences menu and click on downloads. You will see option to install "Command Line Tools" under Components.  After that's installed homebrew stops complaining.

Comment: this is comment not an answer

Comment: @Subhash No, I don't believe it is.

Comment: It's defiantly an answer